# Upload File Using Extjs

Tags: javascript, extjs

Hi I have written a code for uploading a file and to insert into DB, so I need to get the bytes of the uploaded file.

This is my code:

```js
{
  xtype: 'filefield',
  id: 'AttachData',
  name: 'file-path',
  emptyText: 'Upload the document...',
  margin: "15 0 0 0",
  buttonText: 'Browse',
  msgTarget: 'side',
  allowBlank: false,
  anchor: '100%',
  disabled: false
}, {
  xtype: 'button',
  text: 'Upload',
  margin: "15 0 0 10",
  handler: function() {
    var form = this.up('form').getForm();
    if (form.isValid()) {
      form.submit({
        url: '../UploadAttachment.aspx',
        headers: {
          'Content-type': 'application/json;charset=utf-8'
        },
        waitMsg: 'Uploading your file...',
        success: function(response, action) {
          isUploded = true;
          msg('Success', 'Processed file "' + action.result.file + '" on the server');
        },
        failure: function(response, action) {
          console.log(action);
          Ext.Msg.alert('Failed', response.message ? action.result.message : 'No response');
        }
      });
    }
  }
},
```

anyone help me on this concept. Need to get the bytes of the file uploaded.

Comment: This code is working in your environment ? You are uploading and inserting to db ? Or there is some problem with that ? Or  you need just information about size of file ? Could you specify that ?

Answer (score 1):

When your request will go to "UploadAttachment.aspx" page, Just create a function there to get uploaded file details and specify the function name with URL. So that function easily call to server side or in aspx page.

You can get complete details of uploaded files by using below code.

```
HttpPostedFile uploadFile = Context.Request.Files["file-path"];
```

Now you can get all information about uploaded file in uploadFile variable.

Ex.

```
uploadFile.InputStream
uploadFile.FileName
and all others.
```

Default.aspx (Coding)

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="_Default" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <script src="Libraries/ext-all.js"></script>
    <script src="Libraries/ext-all-debug.js"></script>
    <link href="Libraries/ext-theme-crisp-all-debug.css" rel="stylesheet" />

    <script type="text/javascript">

        Ext.onReady(function () {
            var window = new Ext.Window({
                id: 'grdWindow',
                width: 400,
                items: [
                    {
                        xtype: 'form',
                        renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
                        items: [
                            {
                                xtype: 'filefield',
                                id: 'AttachData',
                                name: 'file-path',
                                emptyText: 'Upload the document...',
                                margin: "15 0 0 0",
                                buttonText: 'Browse1',
                                msgTarget: 'side',
                                allowBlank: false,
                                anchor: '100%',
                                disabled: false
                            }, {
                                xtype: 'button',
                                text: 'Upload',
                                handler: function () {
                                    var form = this.up('form').getForm();
                                    if (form.isValid()) {
                                        form.submit({
                                            url: 'Default.aspx',
                                            headers: {
                                                'Content-type': 'application/json;charset=utf-8'
                                            },
                                            waitMsg: 'Uploading your file...',
                                            success: function (response, action) {
                                                isUploded = true;
                                                msg('Success', 'Processed file "' + action.result.file + '" on the server');
                                            },
                                            failure: function (response, action) {
                                                console.log(action);
                                                Ext.Msg.alert('Failed', response.message ? action.result.message : 'No response');
                                            }
                                        });
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                ]
            }).show();
        });

        </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>

    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Default.aspx.cs (Handler)

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        HttpPostedFile fileUpload =  HttpContext.Current.Request.Files["file-path"];
        if (fileUpload != null)
        { 
            //You can get here anything from fileUpload
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: sorry for late reply.. i tried that but that throws exception.. iam new to this technology..\

Comment: It should not  like as you are saying because i have used it many times. If form submit is working and function is calling on server side then you can get any component by Context.Request by giving name of component. Just try again otherwise i will give complete code later.

Comment: while debugging, the breakpoint in aspx file is not hitting, it says no symbols have been loaded for this document

Comment: I have tested your JS code and there is no mistake in your JS code. Just check you have used xtype: 'form' and URL is correct. If still you are not able to solve this issue,then i give code to you. You are sending server to aspx but i tried in ashx ( normal handler for server side code)

Comment: After uploading file, when you click on upload button, just try to send request to ashx instead of aspx then breakpoint will be hit surely. Let me know if still you are facing problem.

Comment: I have updated my answers and added complete coding of both file. Just check it and let me know if you still get any issue.

Comment: Hi.. I written my upload in a .js file.. i have created a panel to place this upload thing.

Comment: Hi.. I written my upload in a .js file.. i have created a panel to place this upload thing.